# How to animate a draggable pushpin

Tags: silverlight, bing-maps, pushpin

I'm looking for a way to show the motion of a push-pin being dragged over the map.
I've tried to modify an example proposed here: 
http://peteohanlon.wordpress.com/2010/10/10/draggable-pushpins/ by updating the AssociatedObject.Location in delegate added to MouseMove event handler, but this makes no results. The push-pin remains at it's place till the moment when the mouse button is released. Then it jumps to the new location.

Any idea how can I force the MapLayer to keep track of the push-pin location during the drag and redraw it properly as mouse moves?

Comment: When I use the same behavior on a push-pin hard-coded into XAML the approach works just as expected - 100%. So probably the usage of binded push-pin (through MapItemsControl-ItemTemplate-DataTemplate) is to blame...

Comment: I think I found the culprit - it's ContentPresenter. The moment the push-pin is it's child it doesn't animate any more.

Answer (score 1):

Max, can you clarify what you want to do? Your approach here sounds reasonable, but having the map recalculate the pin's location every time the mouse moves is a bit uneeded. What about something like this?:

1. When the pin goes into drag mode, it's removed from the map and replaced with a draggable pin that only exists in screen space.  So the user is dragging the "pin" around in screen-space, not map space.
2. When the user ends the drag you convert the screen position to map position (a Location object), and then add it back to the map.

Comment: Your proposal is feasible, I think, and would probably answer the requirement. I was trying to find a simple way to enable this behavior. My original approach works fine (see the comment) for a trivial case - when a hard-XAML-coded push-pin is used.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while working up my own solution, and I was so happy to see it working exactly as you describe I figured I'd post it.  To note, I am also using a 2Way MVVM Binding pattern and it works flawlessly.  You need 2 things:

1)  This extension method to help find the MapLayer that is parent to the pin at runtime:

```
    public static T FindVisualParent<T>(this DependencyObject obj)
    where T : DependencyObject
    {
        DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
        while (parent != null)
        {
            T typed = parent as T;
            if (typed != null)
            {
                return typed;
            }
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

2)  In the Dragging event handler on the pushpin, call that extension method to reference hosting MapLayer and then fire off the most beauteous InvalidateArrange method (from UIElement) as follows:

```
    void ParentMap_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var map = sender as Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.Map;
        var parentLayer = this.FindVisualParent<MapLayer>();

        if (this.isDragging)
        {
            var mouseMapPosition = e.GetPosition(map);
            var mouseGeocode = map.ViewportPointToLocation(mouseMapPosition);
            this.Location = mouseGeocode;
            parentLayer.InvalidateArrange();
        }
    }
```

That should asynchronously perform the visual update and give you a nice slide-around behavior on the pin drag.  HTH

Answer (score 0):

There is a ready to use solution in the Silverlight Toolkit for WP7 over the GestureListener:

```
<my:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location}">
<toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
  <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta"  DragStarted="GestureListener_DragStarted"  DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted"/>
</toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
 </my:Pushpin>

private void GestureListener_DragStarted(object sender, DragStartedGestureEventArgs e)
{
Map.IsEnabled = false;
}

private void GestureListener_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedGestureEventArgs e)
{
Map.IsEnabled = true;
}

private void GestureListener_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
{
Point p = e.GetPosition(Map);
App.ViewModel.Location = Map.ViewportPointToLocation(p);
}
```